# np.ndarray.flatten does not flatten

Tags: python, numpy, flatten

For some odd reason, in some specific case my `np.ndarray` refuses to flatten itself. The only way I can distinguish (I inspected the way the ndarrays are structured) between the different cases is that the ndarray that refuses to flatten is much larger than the other ndarrays.

Anyway, I believe the following behaviour should never occur, right?

```
>>> print(type(myVar))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> print(myVar[0:2])
[array([1, 2]) array([5, 2])]
>>> print(myVar.flatten()[0:2])
[array([1, 2]) array([5, 2])]
```

What is going on here? Why is my array not flattened? It should output:

```
[1 2]
```

Comment: Can you include the definition for myVar?

Comment: Try using `np.stack` to flatten the object dtype layering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you've inadvertently created a one dimensional object array, probably by including rows of different length similar to the following code.

```
>>> t = array([randint(0,3,2) for _ in range(3)] + [3])
>>> print(t[0:2])
[array([0, 0]) array([1, 2])]
```

If you examine the array rather than printing it this becomes apparent (notice that `dtype=object`).

```
>>> t
array([array([0, 0]), array([1, 2]), array([1, 1]), 3], dtype=object)
```

And it would give the behavior you're seeing with flatten, which is the correct behavior for an array of objects.

```
>>> t.flatten()[0:2]
array([array([0, 0]), array([1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

**edit** Don't print the array and try to guess the shape, use `myVar.shape`.  That will tell you exactly how `numpy` is treating the data. Same thing for the number of dimensions and other properties.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the case. I fixed it by using np.hstack(myVar) instead.